# Using a string variable in the url of background-image; css?

Tags: css

```
{
        var mu=a[k];
     function slide() {
         document.getElementById("ss").style.height = "300px";


         document.getElementById("ss").style.backgroundImage = "url( mu)";
         document.write(mu); 

     }
```

the height is being set, and mu string is printed, but the background image doesn't change
whys isn't the background-image changing?

Comment: Try `"url( "+mu+")";`

Answer (score 0):

Right now you aren't using `mu` as a variable, you simply have it as part of your string.

`"url(" + mu + ")"` is what you are seeking.